# Concatenating multiple cells based on changing cell value in same DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

I have a large dataframe and I am trying to figure out how to concatenate cells with different values into one cell, given the following dataframe:
DF1: with Data and Name as headers

```
    Data,                          Name
    Address 213,                   Name1
    Household = 1,                 Name1
    1012 ..alpha numeric value..., Name1
    1013 ..alpha numeric value..., Name1
    1012 ..alpha num val2...       Name1
    1013 ..alpha num val2...       Name1
    Address 234,                   Name2
    Household = 2,                 Name2
    1012 ..alpha numeric value..., Name2
    1013 ..alpha numeric value..., Name2
    1012 ..alpha num val2...       Name2
    1013 ..alpha num val2...       Name2
    .......... dataframe repeats with different values for 10,000+ lines
```

1012 and 1013 is a repeated sequence X amount of times. 
The output I am trying to get is:
DFOut:

```
    Data                                                                                      Name
    Address 213   Household = 1   1012 ..alpha numeric value.. 1013 ..alpha numeric value..., Name1
    Address 213   Household = 1   1012 ..alpha num val2...     1013 ..alpha num val2...,      Name1
    Address 234   Household = 2   1012 ..alpha numeric value.. 1013 ..alpha numeric value..., Name2
    Address 234   Household = 2   1012 ..alpha num val2...     1013 ..alpha num val2...,      Name2
    ..... repeats for entire dataframe 10,000+ lines in DF1
```

Alternatively, cells in the `Data` column in DFOut can also be separated:

```
    Data,         Number,         Seq,                          Seq1,                          Name
    Address 213,  Household = 1,  1012 ..alpha numeric value.., 1013 ..alpha numeric value..., Name1
    Address 213,  Household = 1,  1012 ..alpha num val2...,     1013 ..alpha num val2...,      Name1
    Address 234,  Household = 2,  1012 ..alpha numeric value.., 1013 ..alpha numeric value..., Name2
    Address 234,  Household = 2,  1012 ..alpha num val2...,     1013 ..alpha num val2...,      Name2
    ..... repeats for entire dataframe 10,000+ lines in DF1
```

I attempted to use a few `for` loops to search the `Data` column based on values and then concatenating the different values into one column, but I loose the `Name` column for some reason after doing so. I am fairly new to Python and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
dfgrp0 = df.groupby("Name")["Data"].apply(list).reset_index()

dfgrp1 = dfgrp[['Data', 'Number', 'Seq1', 'Seq2']] = pd.DataFrame(dfgrp['Data'].to_list())
```

**Output:**

`dfgrp0`

```
Name        Data
0   Name1   [Address 213, Household = 1, 1012 ..alpha nume...
1   Name2   [Address 234, Household = 2, 1012 ..alpha nume...
```

`dfgrp1`

```
    Name    Data        Number          Seq1                       Seq2
0   Name1   Address 213 Household = 1   1012 ..alpha numeric value  1013 ..alpha numeric value
1   Name2   Address 234 Household = 2   1012 ..alpha numeric value  1013 ..alpha numeric value
```

I'm not sure what your use case is - this might need some tweaking as it makes some assumptions about your data - but if you want to be really fancy:

```
df['k'] = df['Data'].str.split(' ').map(lambda _: _[0])
df['v'] = df['Data'].str.split(' ').map(lambda _: ' '.join(_[1:]).strip('='))

df.drop('Data', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_out = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Name"], columns=["k"], values=["v"], aggfunc=np.sum)
df_out
```

Output:

```
    v
k       1012                    1013                    Address Household
Name                
Name1   ..alpha numeric value   ..alpha numeric value   213     1
Name2   ..alpha numeric value   ..alpha numeric value   234     2
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your input! I edited my question above. My problem is that 1012 and 1013 is a repeated sequence with different values. Is there a way to group cells just based on their values of 1012, 1013, address, etc? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by iterating via and using string concatenation. Just make sure the `Data` column is a string type.

```
DF1["Data"] = DF1["Data"].astype('str') # Convert "Data" column to string type
DF1_grouped = DF1.groupby("Name") # Create groups
DFOut = DF1_grouped["Data"].sum() # Concatenate strings
```

Single line solution

```
DFOut = DF1.groupby("Name")["Data"].sum()
```

If you want space after each `Data` value, you can add that to the column after string conversion and before the grouping.

```
DF1["Data"] = DF1["Data"] + " " # Add space after each string
```

Comment: Hi Rookie, thanks for your input, I updated my question above, 1012 and 1013 is a repeated sequence with different values. Is there a way I can group by the changing values in each row? Please let me know if you want more clarification. Thanks again.